# store non mandatory fields in the database

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, laravel-5.7

> I am trying to insert data into the database with following fields
>   except few which are not mandatory(licensename,licensenumber and
>   file).
>
> signup.blade.php

```
            var lic = [];
            var licname = [];
            var licnum = [];
            var licfile = [];

            $('#country1').select2();
            $('#sign_up1').click(function () {
                var lic_group = [];
                fname = $("#fname1").val();
                lname = $("#lname1").val();
                country = $('#country1').select2('data').text;
                company = $("#company1").val();
                role = "legal";
                designation1 = $("#designation1").val();
                industry = $("#industry1").val();
                dob = $("#dob1_input").val();
                email = $("#email1").val();
                password = $("#password1").val();
                cnf_password = $("#cnf_password1").val();
                practices = $("#practices").val();
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append("fname", fname);
                data.append("lname", lname);
                data.append("country", country);
                data.append("company", company);
                data.append("role", role);
                data.append("designation", designation1);
                data.append("industry", industry);
                data.append("dob", dob);
                data.append("email", email);
                data.append("password", password);
                data.append("practices", practices);
                var i = 0;
                $("[id^=main_lic_]").each(function () {
                    data.append('licname_' + i, $(this).find('.lic_name').val());
                    data.append('lic_no_' + i, $(this).find('.lic_no').val());
                    data.append('lic_file_' + i, $(this).find('.lic_file')[0].files[0]);
                    i++;
                });
                if (fname == "" || lname == "" || country == "" || company == "" || designation1 == "" || industry == "" || dob == "" || email == "" || password == "" || practices == "") {
                    show_notification("error", "Please enter all required fields");
                } else {
                    if (password != cnf_password) {
                        show_notification("error", "Password and confirm password doesn't match");
                    }
                    else {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "reg",
                            type: "POST",
                            headers: {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                            },
                            data: data,
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.msg == "Register Successful") {
                                    show_notification("success", "Registered Successfully");
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        window.location.href = "/";
                                    }, 1000);
                                }

                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                show_notification("error", data.responseJSON.message);
                            },
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false
                        });
                    }
                }

            });
```

> UserController.php

```
public function registerLawyer(Request $request)
    {
        $firstname = $request->get('fname');
        $lastname = $request->get('lname');
        $country = $request->get('country');
        $company = $request->get('company');
        $role = $request->get('role');
        $desig = $request->get('designation');
        $dob = $request->get('dob');
        $email = $request->get('email');
        $pass = $request->get('password');
        $indus_sec = $request->get('industry');
        $all_params = $request->keys();
        $total_licenses = preg_grep("/^licname_.*/", $all_params);
        if($role == 'legal' && ($request->get('licname_0') == null || $request->get('lic_no_0') == null || $request->file('lic_file_0') == null)){
            abort(403, 'Institute License is mandatory');
        }
        $userWithExistingEmail = User::where('email', $email)->first();
        if ($userWithExistingEmail) {
            abort(403, 'Account already exists with this email');
        }
        if(!in_array($role, ['legal', 'client'])){
            abort(403, 'Invalid role request');
        }

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->firstname = $firstname;
        $user->lastname = $lastname;
        $user->country = $country;
        $user->company = $company;
        $user->role = $role;
        $user->designation = $desig;
        $user->dob = Carbon::parse($dob)->toDateString();
        $user->status = ($request->get('role') == 'legal') ? 0 : 1;
        $user->password = bcrypt($pass);
        $user->save();
       /* foreach (explode(',', $request->get('industry')) as $userIndustry){
            $uIndustry = new UserIndustry();
            $uIndustry->user_id = $user->id;
            $uIndustry->industrysector_id = $userIndustry;
            $uIndustry->save();
        }*/
        if($role == 'legal'){
            $lawyer = new Lawyer();
            $lawyer->user_id = $user->id;
            $lawyer->save();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($total_licenses); $i++) {
                $filename = $request->file('lic_file_0' . $i)->store('licenses');
                $licenseno1 = $request->get('licname_0' . $i);
                $licenseName = $request->get('lic_no_0' . $i);
                $license = new License();
                if($filename != null && $licenseno1 != null && $licenseName != null){
                    $license->lawyer_id = $lawyer->id;
                    $license->file = $filename;
                    $license->institution = $licenseName;
                    $license->licenseno = $licenseno1;
                    $license->save();
                }else{
                    $license->lawyer_id = $lawyer->id;
                    $license->save();
                }

            }
            foreach(explode(',', $request->get('practices')) as $aop){
                $uAop = new UserAOP();
                $uAop->user_id = $user->id;
                $uAop->aop_id = $aop;
                $uAop->save();
            }
        }
        return ['msg' => 'Register Successful'];
    }
```

In this i want to keep $filename,$licenseno1 and $licenseName as non mandatory means user can leave this fields blank can i achieve this without making making this fields nullble;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't store null value in the db without allowing null.

Comment: That's the main condition ,i cannot make it nullable

Comment: setting something default according to your application and treat that as null